# Obtaining metadata "Where from" of a file on Mac

Tags: python, macos, metadata, spotlight

I am trying to obtain the "Where from" extended file attribute which is located on the "get info" context-menu of a file in MacOS.

### Example

When right-clicking on the file and displaying the info it shows the this metadata.

The highlighted part in the image below shows the information I want to obtain (the link of the website where the file was downloaded from).

[image: 'Where from' on MacOS file info]

I want to use this Mac-specific function using Python.
I thought of using OS tools but couldn't figure out any.

Comment: This is stored in the kMDItemWhereFroms item in the file metadata, and can be shown using the `mdls` unix command. I don't know how to get to that from Python, but maybe this gives you some more keywords to search for. :) (Well, obviously you could always do `subprocess.run("mdls ...")` but that does not seem very elegant.)

Comment: @TurePålsson, thanks for sharing the MetaData (MD) utils like [`mdls`](https://ss64.com/osx/mdls.html) to list the metadata attributes for a specified file. If you like, contribute your comment to my answer ️

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Get the *extended attribute* like MacOS's "Where from" by e.g. pip-install [`pyxattr`](https://pypi.org/project/pyxattr/) and use `xattr.getxattr("file.pdf", "com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms")`.

### Extended Attributes on files

These [*extended file attributes*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes) like your "Where From" in MacOS (since 10.4) store metadata not interpreted by the filesystem. They exist for different operating systems.

#### using the command-line

You can also query them on the command-line with tools like:

- [`exiftool`](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/378120/371189):

```sh
exiftool -MDItemWhereFroms -MDItemTitle -MDItemAuthors -MDItemDownloadedDate /path/to/file
```

- [`xattr`](https://ss64.com/osx/xattr.html) (apparently [MacOS also uses a Python-script](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/125884/why-is-xattr-not-working))

```sh
xattr -p -l -x /path/to/file
```

On MacOS many [attributes are displayed in *property-list* format](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6525/editing-iphoto-specific-metadata), thus use `-x` option to obtain hexadecimal output.

#### using Python

[Ture Pålsson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70444996/obtaining-where-from-information-of-a-file-on-mac/70446742#comment124525867_70444996) pointed out the missing link **keywords**. Such common and appropriate terms are helpful to search [Python Package Index (PyPi)](https://pypi.org/):

Search PyPi by keywords: *extend file attributes*, *meta data*:

- [`xattr`](https://pypi.org/project/pyxattr/)
- [`pyxattr`](https://pypi.org/project/xattr/)
- [`osxmetadata`](https://pypi.org/project/osxmetadata/), requires Python 3.7+, MacOS only

For example to list and get attributes use (adapted from [pyxattr's official  docs](https://pyxattr.k1024.org/readme.html#basic-example))

```py
import xattr

xattr.listxattr("file.pdf")
# ['user.mime_type', 'com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms']
xattr.getxattr("file.pdf", "user.mime_type")
# 'text/plain'
xattr.getxattr("file.pdf", "com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms")
# ['https://example.com/downloads/file.pdf']
```

However you will have to convert the MacOS specific metadata which is stored in *plist* format, e.g. using [`plistlib`](https://docs.python.org/library/plistlib.html).

### File metadata on MacOS

Mac OS X 10.4 (Tiger) introduced [Spotlight](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/mac-os-x/9780596520625/ch02.html) a system for extracting (or harvesting), storing, indexing, and querying **metadata**. It provides an integrated system-wide service for searching and indexing.

This metadata is stored as *extended file attributes* having [keys prefixed with `com.apple.metadata:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/file_metadata/mditem/common_metadata_attribute_keys). The "Where from" attribute for example has the key `com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms`.

#### using Python

Use *osxmetadata* to use similar functionality like in MacOS's [`md*` utils](https://real-world-systems.com/docs/mdfind.1.html):

```py
from osxmetadata import OSXMetaData

filename = 'file.pdf'
meta = OSXMetaData(filename)

# get and print "Where from" list, downloaded date, title
print(meta.wherefroms, meta.downloadeddate, meta.title)
```

#### See also

- MacIssues (2014): [How to look up file metadata in OS X](https://macissues.com/2014/05/12/how-to-look-up-file-metadata-in-os-x/)
- OSXDaily (2018): [How to View & Remove Extended Attributes from a File on Mac OS](https://osxdaily.com/2018/05/03/view-remove-extended-attributes-file-mac/)
- Ask Different: [filesystem - What all file metadata is available in macOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/274744/what-all-file-metadata-is-available-in-macos)
- [Query Spotlight for a range of dates via PyObjC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852821/query-spotlight-for-a-range-of-dates-via-pyobjc)
- [Mac OS X : add a custom meta data field to any file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8530825/mac-os-x-add-a-custom-meta-data-field-to-any-file)

Answer (score 1):

macOS stores metadata such as the ["Where from"](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/kmditemwherefroms) attribute under the key `com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms`.

```
import xattr

value = xattr.getxattr("sublime_text_build_4121_mac.zip",'com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms').decode("ISO-8859-1")

print(value)

'bplist00¢\x01\x02_\x10@https://download.sublimetext.com/sublime_text_build_4121_mac.zip_\x10\x1chttps://www.sublimetext.com/\x08\x0bN\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00m'
```

I had faced a similar problem long ago. We did not use Python to solve it.

Comment: That binary chunk can probably be decoded to something nicer using `plistlib.loads()`.